# How to combine more than 10 cvs files into one data frame in R?

Tags: r

I've tried several ways that are already discussed about this issue in stack overflow, but still can't do this. I have more than 10 cvs files in my computer. I want to combine (cbind) each file into one big data frame. And I want to have column names as a name of each file. Any ideas?

Comment: What do you mean by "column names as a name of each file", do you want the name of the .csv or the name of the variable(s) in the .csv? How many columns have the .csv. Please add more details.

Comment: If I try to combine files named "AAA" and "BBB", in a combined file, every column names of "AAA" should be AAA. Does it make sense?

Comment: @DongchulPark a data frame needs to have unique column names. Do you mean you want to *append* the file names to the column names? Like "fileX_colY"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use `read.csv` in an `lapply`; when you `cbind` afterwards, the names get attached as prefix to the column names. (List should be named of course.)

```
f.names <- c("file1.csv", "file2.csv", "file3.csv")

res <- do.call(cbind, setNames(lapply(f.names, read.csv), gsub("\\.csv$", "",  f.names)))
res
#   file1.a file1.b file1.c file1.d file2.a file2.b file2.c file2.d file3.a file3.b
# 1       1       4       7      10       1       4       7      10       1       4
# 2       2       5       8      11       2       5       8      11       2       5
# 3       3       6       9      12       3       6       9      12       3       6
#   file3.c file3.d
# 1       7      10
# 2       8      11
# 3       9      12
```

---

*Data:*

```
df0 <- data.frame(matrix(1:12, 3, 4, dimnames=list(NULL, letters[1:4])))
sapply(1:3, function(i) write.csv(df0, file=sprintf("file%s.csv", i), row.names=FALSE))
```

Comment: I think my question was not clear. Sorry about that and thank you for your work.